# Hadoop context.write() output prints NaN with a Text object

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, output, nan

This is my first time using Hadoop, and I'm having trouble writing to my output file. When I print the value with a System.out it displays fine, but using context.write(key, value) the value prints as NaN.

Example:

```
System.out.println(stockName.toString() + " " + result.toString());
```

outputs correctly to userlogs:

```
AAPL.csv 0.076543
```

But using:

```
context.write(stockName, result);
```

Outputs:

```
AAPL.csv NaN
```

result and stockName are both Text() objects that were set previously.

I have also included my entire reduce function. Any ideas would be great as I have tried just about everything I can think of, thanks!

```
public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

    private Text stockName = new Text();

    private ArrayList<Float> monthlyReturn = new ArrayList<Float>();
    private String previousMonth = "";
    private float numOfMonths = 0;

    private float startPrice = 0;
    private float endPrice = 0;

    private Text result = new Text();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        // Set the Stock Name as the Key
        stockName.set(key);

        for (Text val: values) {

            System.out.println(val);

            // Parse date & adjusted close
            String[] stockValues = val.toString().split(",");
            if (stockValues.length < 2) { 
                continue;
            }

            String month = stockValues[0];
            String priceInput = stockValues[1];

            float closingPrice = Float.parseFloat(priceInput);

            // First time around setup.
            if (startPrice == 0 && previousMonth.equals("")) {
                startPrice = closingPrice;
                previousMonth = month;
            }

            /*
             * We check if the month has changed, and that we're not just starting.
             * If the month changed, increment the number of months we have seen, and run a calculation
             * for monthly return.
             * 
             * closePrice is set to every stock value. The startPrice is only set when the month changes.
             * When the month does change, we take the last set closePrice to run our calculation, and 
             * then set the new startPrice.
             */
            if (!month.equals(previousMonth) && endPrice != 0) {
                numOfMonths += 1;
                monthlyReturn.add((endPrice - startPrice)/startPrice);
                startPrice = closingPrice;
            }
            previousMonth = month;
            endPrice = closingPrice;
        }


        // Add on the last month value
        numOfMonths += 1;
        monthlyReturn.add((endPrice - startPrice)/startPrice);

        /*
         * Generate the volatility. The equation is as follows:
         * 
         * 1. xbar       = sum(xi)/numOfMonth -> sum is over all values from 0 to N in monthlyReturn
         * 2. xsum       = sum( (xi-xbar)^2 ) from 0 to N in monthlyReturn
         * 3. volatility = sqrt( (1/numOfMonth-1)*xsum )
         */

        // 1.
        float xiSum = 0;
        for (int i =0; i<monthlyReturn.size(); i++) {
            xiSum += monthlyReturn.get(i);
        }
        float xBar = xiSum/numOfMonths;

        // 2.
        double xSum = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<monthlyReturn.size(); i++) {
            xSum += Math.pow(monthlyReturn.get(i) - xBar, 2);
        }

        // 3.
        double root = (1/(numOfMonths-1))*xSum;
        result.set(String.valueOf(Math.sqrt(root)));

        System.out.println(stockName.toString() + " " + result.toString());
        context.write(stockName, result);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Job job = Job.getInstance();
    job.setJarByClass(StockVolatility.class);

    job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);


    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    job.waitForCompletion(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont use job.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
My issue was resolved after I did that.